# Multiple Protocols in One Connection

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a very strange situation to where a TCP server basically maintains two protocols. The first message pair sends STX|PAYLOAD|ETX messages and returns the same STX|PAYLOAD|ETX message type.

Another message pair sends STX|PAYLOAD|ETX messages but only returns |PAYLOAD| (No STX/ETX bytes).

I've created a custom Serializer/Deserializer to handle the anomaly, but the error I'm receiving is happening when the connection is received (as shown below in the stack trace).

Using CTRL on the server for test purposes enables me to receive the messages. So, what I believe is happening is that the AbstractConnectionFactory uses the ByteArrayCrLfSerializer by default. When I'm trying to use the custom Serializer, however, the connection factory doesn't know how to render the message with no STX/ETX bytes. What I need to do is simply read the response. Please advise...

```
    @Bean
    FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverClientFactory() {
        FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverClientConnectionFactory = new FailoverClientConnectionFactory(underlyingCF());
        failoverClientConnectionFactory.setSingleUse(true);
        return failoverClientConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> underlyingCF() {

        List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> connections = new ArrayList<AbstractClientConnectionFactory>();
        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory primary = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(primaryTcpServerHost, primaryTcpServerPort);
        primary.setSerializer(new ByteArrayClientSerializer());
        primary.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayClientSerializer());
        primary.setSingleUse(true);
        log.info("Starting with Primary Server/Port as: {}:{}", primaryTcpServerHost, primaryTcpServerPort);

        TcpNioClientConnectionFactory failover = new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(secondaryTcpServerHost, secondaryTcpServerPort);
        failover.setSerializer(new ByteArrayClientSerializer());
        primary.setDeserializer(new ByteArrayClientSerializer());
        failover.setSingleUse(true);
        log.info("Starting with Secondary Server/Port as: {}:{}", secondaryTcpServerHost, secondaryTcpServerPort);

        connections.add(primary);
        connections.add(failover);

        return connections;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("failoverClientFactory")
    public IntegrationFlow liveMumClient() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Gate.class)
                .handle(Tcp.outboundGateway(failoverClientFactory()))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .get();
    }

    public interface Gate {
        // TODO: Use properties for 20000 seems to be unsupported 
        @Gateway(replyTimeout = 5000)
        String sendAndReceive(byte[] out);
    }
}
```

```
private Deserializer<?> deserializer = new ByteArrayCrLfSerializer();
```

```
    private static final byte[] CRLF = "\r\n".getBytes();

    @Override
    public void serialize(byte[] bytes, OutputStream outputStream)
            throws IOException {
        outputStream.write(bytes);
        outputStream.write(CRLF); // DOESN'T WORK WHEN REMOVED AND I NEED TO READ RAW BYTES IN THIS CASE.
    }
```

Client-Side Serializer

```
@Slf4j
public class ByteArrayClientSerializer extends AbstractPooledBufferByteArraySerializer {

    /**
     * A single reusable instance.
     */
    public static final ByteArrayLiveMumSerializer INSTANCE = new ByteArrayLiveMumSerializer();

    public static final int STX = 0x02;

    public static final int ETX = 0x03;

    /**
     * Reads the data in the inputStream to a byte[]. Data must be prefixed
     * with an ASCII STX character, and terminated with an ASCII ETX character.
     * Throws a {@link SoftEndOfStreamException} if the stream
     * is closed immediately before the STX (i.e. no data is in the process of
     * being read).
     *
     */
    @Override
    public byte[] doDeserialize(InputStream inputStream, byte[] buffer) throws IOException {

        int bite = inputStream.read();
        if (bite < 0) {
            throw new SoftEndOfStreamException("Stream closed between payloads");
        }
        int n = 0;

        try {
            if (bite == STX) {
                while ((bite = inputStream.read()) != ETX) {
                    checkClosure(bite);
                    buffer[n++] = (byte) bite;
                    if (n >= getMaxMessageSize()) {
                        throw new IOException("ETX not found before max message length: "
                                + getMaxMessageSize());
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                while (bite >= 0) {
                    try {
                        bite = inputStream.read();
                    }
                    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
                        bite = -1;
                    }
                    if (bite < 0) {
                        if (n == 0) {
                            throw new SoftEndOfStreamException("Stream closed between payloads");
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    if (n >= getMaxMessageSize()) {
                        throw new IOException("Socket was not closed before max message length: "
                                + getMaxMessageSize());
                    }
                    buffer[n++] = (byte) bite;
                }
                byte[] bytes = copyToSizedArray(buffer, n);
                System.out.println("Deserialized: " + new String(bytes));
            }
            return copyToSizedArray(buffer, n);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            publishEvent(e, buffer, n);
            throw e;
        }
        catch (RuntimeException e) {
            publishEvent(e, buffer, n);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Writes the byte[] to the stream, prefixed by an ASCII STX character and
     * terminated with an ASCII ETX character.
     */
    @Override
    public void serialize(byte[] bytes, OutputStream os) throws IOException {

        os.write(STX);
        os.write(bytes);
        os.write(ETX);
    }
}
```

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Exception while awaiting reply; nested exception is java.io.EOFException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway$AsyncReply.doThrowErrorMessagePayload(TcpOutboundGateway.java:419) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway$AsyncReply.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:408) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.getReply(TcpOutboundGateway.java:209) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:161) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) [spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:233) [spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) [spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:46) [spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:97) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:38) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:96) [spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(AbstractMessagingTemplate.java:86) [spring-messaging-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:495) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:469) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.sendOrSendAndReceive(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:564) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:489) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:464) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:453) [spring-integration-core-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.sendAndReceive(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at gov.nyc.mumweb.service.MumWebService.askMum(MumWebService.java:60) [classes/:na]
    at gov.nyc.mumweb.controller.LiveMumController.recommendationService(LiveMumController.java:27) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_141]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Connection is closed
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.lambda$processNioSelections$0(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:722) ~[spring-integration-ip-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_141]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the debug message eliminated the error. Ugh!

```
System.out.println("Deserialized: " + new String(bytes));
```